# Cox regression Not significant on univariate but significant on multivariate

Tags: cox-model

I am doing an observational review of survival times between two groups who received a different drug. There are some baseline differences between the groups(sex and age distributions are for example). When doing univariate cox regression drug A has a less hazard of death but the p-value is 0.47. When I performed multivariate analysis on variables with p-values less than 0.2 including basics such as sex, age, comorbidities, time to receiving treatment etc.. Drug A is significantly better than drug B with a p-value of 0.04. I was surprised to see this. Am I missing something with model design? I categorized a lot of variables in the multivariate. Should I have attempted an inverse propensity weights? Either way could this truly be or am I making some error with my multivariable model design? 
Thanks!

Comment: Why exactly are you surprised? In principle I would not ever trust a university analysis of observational data. The regression adjustment vs. propensity scores is well discussed in the standard literature.

Comment: @Björn I wouldn't trust anyone's PK analysis, including industry's. The models are 19$^{th}$ century and there is little interest in better modelling. E.g., see [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_volume_pharmacokinetic_models).

Comment: Arrg, that was meant to be univariate, not university. Swype does that sometimes.

Comment: @Björn (+1) for OP so he isn't frightened off. Expand your comment to be an answer and I'll upvote that too.

Comment: Thank you for your help so far. I was more surprised that my primary outcome variable with a p=0.47 became significant on multivariate and making sure I am not missing something. Since there was also a significantly different distribution between my groups on some variables such as female sex lets say and this variable was significant on univariate and multivariate analysis I am not somehow skewing my data.